# Signal from pthread to main

Tags: c, pthreads, signals

```
pthread_t thread_id;
while(1) {
   if(counter < 3) {
      // do something
      pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL , handle_me, (void*)arg);
   }
   else {
      // wait for counter to be changed 
      // pthreads will be changing the counter 
      // when changed, go back to beginning of loop 
      counter++;
   }
}
```

i am trying to achieve the following: signal from a `pthread` to main. 
what options do i have ?

counter is protected by a `mutex` when changed in threads.

Comment: You likely need a [condition variable](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables). And that `counter` check in your loop should not be done without the mutex protecting `counter` being latched, btw.

Comment: Can i make the main wait for it to be signaled from a thread ? Why do i have in mind that i can signal from a thread to another thread.

Comment: Your requirements are vague-at-best, indecipherable for most. What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: My explanation above is exactly what i want. I had a misconception of using condition variables but now its all cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a condition variable. From the thread incrementing the counter use `pthread_cond_signal` or `pthread_cond_broadcast`. In the other thread that waits for the signal, use `pthread_cond_wait` or `pthread_cond_timedwait`.